# JGraphT SimpleGraph and UndirectedGraph

Tags: java, android, jgrapht

I want make Graph using JGraphT Library.
My code is below:

```
private UndirectedGraph<State, DefaultEdge> graph;
private HashMap<String, State> vertixList;

public  MapGraph(HashMap<String, State> vertixList, List<Transition> transList) {
    graph = new SimpleGraph<State, DefaultEdge>(DefaultEdge.class);
    this.vertixList = vertixList;

    // add all vertices
    for(State s : vertixList.values())
        graph.addVertex(s);

    // add all transitions
    for(Transition t : transList)
        graph.addEdge(t.start, t.end);

}
```

But it has compile error.

```
error: incompatible types: SimpleGraph<State,DefaultEdge> cannot be converted 
to UndirectedGraph<State,DefaultEdge>
```

It occurs line 5. (`graph = new SimpleGraph`)
What can I do? Need help...
(I'm using Android Studio!)

Comment: please write a proper working example. Remove stuff that's not important. This for instance works fine:
private UndirectedGraph<Integer, DefaultEdge> graph;

public Test(){
    graph = new SimpleGraph<>(DefaultEdge.class);
    System.out.println(graph);
}

Answer (score 1):

You have declared your variable `graph` like

```
private UndirectedGraph<State, DefaultEdge> graph;
```

but you try to define it as

```
graph = new SimpleGraph<State, DefaultEdge>(DefaultEdge.class);
```

which will not work due to incompatible types.

Your graph is an `UndirectedGraph` and you assign a `SimpleGraph`.
That is the issue here…

Define it (in line 5) as

```
graph = new UndirectedGraph<State, DefaultEdge>(DefaultEdge.class);
```

Comment: That's not possible. UndirectedGraph is an interface, and SimpleGraph implements this interface.